# Using find to move files with specific conditions

Tags: linux, find

How do I write a find script that moves files in a specific directory two levels up but only if nested below that specific directory? For example...My ipcamera saves files to my NAS in a very poor fashion. It's nested like this.

```
    /volume1
     /ipcamera
      /04302020
       /dav
        /01
         /010000[m]01m01s.dav
         /010202[m]01m04s.dav
        /02
         /020000[m]01m19s.dav
      /04312020
       /dav
        /03
         /030000[m]02m01s.dav
         /030601[m]04m04s.dav
        /08
         /080000[m]01m11s.dav
etc....
```

I want to move ALL these .dav files up to the date folder. They are two levels up. I am assuming something like this would work.

Simply put..
all dav files below the date directory should be moved two folders up. All dav files that have been moved previously and are now in the date directory should not be moved two folder up again (when ran in the future)

`find /volume1/ipcamera -iname '*.dav' -exec mv '{}' ../../ \;`

But my problem is that while it would technically work the first time, the subsequent run would move all the files in the 04302020 directory up two more levels again. How do I limit it so that only moves files that are at least two directories below /volume1/ipcamera so that as the dates change it can adapt itself (without touching any *.dav files in a date folder (only *.dav files in subdirectories).

Comment: Does your `find` support `-mindepth`? Does it support `-execdir`?

Comment: Yes it does, thank you!

Comment: I think `find /volume1/ipcam -mindepth 2 -type f -name '*.dav' -exec sh -c 'cd "$1"; for f in *; do mv -i "$f" ../../ ; done' find-sh {} \;` will work out for me once I tweak it a little and figure out if it's what I am trying to solve.

Comment: Thank you Kamil! Your suggestions on -mindepth and -execdir were on point. I came up with this `find /volume1/ipcamera -mindepth 3 -name '*.dav' -exec mv -i {} ../../../ \;` and it got the files to the directory I needed. Thank you so much!

Comment: Great! Now you can [write an answer](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer). If you decide to do this, keep the answer technical and don't mention me.